# Ruby on Rails: Model's attribute returns a null value when used in Views

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my *seeds.rb* file, I assigned a value to the `name` attribute of my devise model.

```
Admin.create!({email: 'admin@example.com', password: '12341234', password_confirmation: '12341234', name:'Steven'})
```

I want the value of `name` to show in the page when I run the application.

```
<h1>Welcome, <%= current_admin.name %>!</h1>
```

But it does not show the assigned value for `name`.

Comment: can you share the view code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You'll likely get better answers if you read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Then, update your question with example code, console output, errors, etc.

Comment: What does it show currently? BTW how many records you have in admins table?

Comment: Please share your controller and view codes. Also what does return the command `Admin.first` (assuming you have only created one) on your `rails console`?

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like the `name` to appear for just that one hardcoded `admin`, try changing your view to be like this:

```
<h1>Welcome, <%= Admin.first.name %>!</h1>
```

If you'd like the name to be dynamic, you'll need to log in as that admin (and probably want to make sure that page is accessible by only logged in admins).